# how to handle null values when consume Oracle SOA soap service in c#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, soap, service-reference

I'm trying to consume a soap service which developed by Oracle SOA in c# desktop app. I added service reference to the project and developed the code to use the functions inside soap service like this and every time get exception which explained below please help me to solve this issue:-

```
CallCenterServiceReference.CallCenterService_pttClient client = new CallCenterServiceReference.CallCenterService_pttClient();
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "";
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "";
        CallCenterServiceReference.isPowerCutForNotPay obj = new CallCenterServiceReference.isPowerCutForNotPay();
        CallCenterServiceReference.authStruct auth = new CallCenterServiceReference.authStruct();

        obj.agreeNo = serviceIdTextBox.Text;
        obj.DEVID = null;
        obj.FRF = null;
        auth.systemID = 123;
        auth.authKey = "";
        auth.systemIDSpecified = true;
        obj.auth = auth;

        var response = client.isPowerCutForNotPay(obj).isPowerCutForNotPayResult;
        MessageBox.Show("ResultCode is :-"+response.resultCode);
```

Exception happen in this line

```
    var response = client.isPowerCutForNotPay(obj).isPowerCutForNotPayResult;
```

SOAP Request MSG

```
<s:Envelope
    xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <isPowerCutForNotPay
            xmlns="http://www.J.com/SampleApplication/CallCenterSystem">
            <agreeNo>3456</agreeNo>
            <DEVID xsi:nil="true"/>
            <FRF xsi:nil="true"/>
            <auth>
                <authKey>1234565</authKey>
                <systemID>2005</systemID>
            </auth>
        </isPowerCutForNotPay>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Soap Response MSG

```
<env:Envelope
    xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
    <env:Header>
        <wsa:Action>isPowerCutForNotPay</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:MessageID>urn:1d0f3f85-8963-11ee-a4bb-5254003edad5</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:ReplyTo>
            <wsa:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</wsa:Address>
            <wsa:ReferenceParameters>
                <instra:tracking.ecid
                    xmlns:instra="http://xmlns.oracle.com/sca/tracking/1.0">f99958a9-fe21-4f48-871e-eef4aadfc448-007192ac
                </instra:tracking.ecid>
                <instra:tracking.FlowEventId
                    xmlns:instra="http://xmlns.oracle.com/sca/tracking/1.0">70056562
                </instra:tracking.FlowEventId>
                <instra:tracking.FlowId
                    xmlns:instra="http://xmlns.oracle.com/sca/tracking/1.0">122084
                </instra:tracking.FlowId>
                <instra:tracking.CorrelationFlowId
                    xmlns:instra="http://xmlns.oracle.com/sca/tracking/1.0">0000OjsFbzE6iKG6yzvX6G1_8zCF0000ax
                </instra:tracking.CorrelationFlowId>
                <instra:tracking.quiescing.SCAEntityId
                    xmlns:instra="http://xmlns.oracle.com/sca/tracking/1.0">70096
                </instra:tracking.quiescing.SCAEntityId>
            </wsa:ReferenceParameters>
        </wsa:ReplyTo>
        <wsa:FaultTo>
            <wsa:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</wsa:Address>
        </wsa:FaultTo>
    </env:Header>
    <env:Body>
        <isPowerCutForNotPayResponse
            xmlns:ns1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/CallCenter/JDECOCallCenter/JDECOCallCenterService"
            xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
            xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy"
            xmlns:wssutil="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
            xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
            xmlns:ouaf="http://ouaf.oracle.com/"
            xmlns:tns="http://www.J.com/SampleApplication/CallCenterSystem"
            xmlns="http://www.J.com/SampleApplication/CallCenterSystem">
            <tns:isPowerCutForNotPayResult>
                <tns:resultCode>-1</tns:resultCode>
                <tns:resultStringA/>
                <tns:resultStringE>Invalid Account ID</tns:resultStringE>
                <tns:resultStringH/>
                <tns:customMessageA/>
                <tns:customMessageE/>
                <tns:customMessageH/>
                <tns:trans>
                    <tns:DEVID/>
                    <tns:FRF/>
                    <tns:JRF>1373</tns:JRF>
                    <tns:systemID>2005</tns:systemID>
                </tns:trans>
                <tns:value/>
            </tns:isPowerCutForNotPayResult>
        </isPowerCutForNotPayResponse>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

But when I run the application I got this error any one can help me to solve this problem??

> See the end of this message for details on invoking  just-in-time
> (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.
>
> ************** Exception Text ************** System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: Error in deserializing
> body of reply message for operation 'isPowerCutForNotPay'. --->
> System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document
> (1, 2104). ---> System.FormatException: The string '' is not a valid
> Boolean value.    at System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToBoolean(String s)    at
> Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderJDECOCallCenterService_ptt.Read5_Utils_ResultClassOfboolean(Boolean
> isNullable, Boolean checkType)    at

Comment: Your Xml is not valid.  People who generate XML files should always check if the XML is valid before sending to users.  Users should never get errors.  They should always be checked by the people who generate the file.

Comment: In this case from where handling must be fron service or client?

Comment: Are you getting a 200 OK as a response status?  Error could be an error so there is no xml in the body.  If you are generating the request than the xml you generated is not valid.  A response from server should always be valid.

Comment: I get response 200 OK but the problem here when parsing value tag  <tns:value/> this must be bool but when try to parse it in xml return this exception in the code

Comment: The node doesn't have any innertext : <tns:value/>

Comment: but when I get a null value in xml tag is there any way to handle it by the client ?

Comment: The code isn't posted so I cannot give an answer.  If you have classes you can use a question mark to allow null values. Or in the get/set handle the null value. Using Xml Linq you do not use 'value'.  Instead you cast the object to a type.